# Ratcliffe's Text- Theorem 12.3.4 Conical limits points and Euclidian boundary

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

[image]

**QUESTION:** So I tried to see what ratcliffe meant here, but I don't get it. Namely, how does he get a contradiction at the end. I don't see how $P$ being locally finite gives us a contradiction. I assumed that Ratcliffe wanted a contradiction by noting that $g_i\overline{P}$ forms a covering of $B^n$ and by some finagling you get a disjoint infinite open cover of $K$, which contradicts compactness but that doesn't seem to work here.

**EDIT:** DEFINITION: A collection $\mathcal{S}$ of subsets of a topological space $X$ is locally finite if and only if for each point $x$ of $X$, there is an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ in $X$ such that $U$ meets only finitely many members of $S$

DEFINITION: A convex fundamental polyhedron for a discrete group $\Gamma$ of isometries of $X$ is a convex polyhedron $P$ in $X$ whose interior is a locally finite fundamental domain for $\Gamma$.

DEFINITION: A subset $R$ of a metric space $X$ is a fudamental domain for agroup $\Gamma$ of isometries of $X$ iff

(1) The set $R$ is open in X;

(2) The members of ${gR:g\in\Gamma}$ are mutually disjoint; and

(3) $X=\cup{g\overline{R}:g\in\Gamma}$.

(4) $R$ is connected

**EDIT2**: Ok I think I see what the contradiction is. We note that $g_iP$ forms a locally finite collection for $K$. Let $x_j\in K$, then by local finiteness there exists an open subset $U_{x_j}$ that intersects with finitely many elements in our locally finite collection. By compactness we have a finite sub cover $U_{x_1},\cdots,U_{x_n}$. But this collection intersects with only finitely many elements in our infinite collection $g_iP$, and hence only finitely many interest $K$, which contradicts the fact that $K\cap g_iP\neq\emptyset$ for infinitely many elements.

Comment: If there are questions about properties of things used in his proof I can provide further details. The material is extracted from Ratcliffe's text, "Foundations of Hyperbolic Manifolds".

Comment: From what I can tell, the sentence "there is a sequence $\{g_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ of distinct elements of $\Gamma$ and a compact subset $K$ of $B^n$ such that $K \cap g_i P \ne \emptyset$ for all $i$" is a direct contradiction to the definition of local finiteness. So if that is not clear to you, perhaps you can include into your question the definition of local finiteness in Ratcliffe's textbook.

Comment: Your edits look good.